# Installing matlab

Tags: software-installation, matlab

My university has licence of matlab. And wanted download from the link of my school. While I was installing i got this error
\"Error unmounting /dev/sda2: Command-line `umount  "/dev/sda2"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: umount: /: target is busy
        (In some cases useful info about processes that
         use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)
 (udisks-error-quark, 14)"
How will i solve it?

Comment: Installing a software shouldn't require unmounting a partition ?!? Also there's documentation already available: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB

Comment: Here it says firs mount the iso file but i don`t know how to do it?

Comment: From ISO / From download are two different options. If you want the first one, the instructions are there too - "(...) *right-click, open with... (...)*... What's the problem exactly?